# I want to add photo in emulator using visual Studio code

Tags: emulation, photo

I am able to add photos through Android studio file explorer but I want to add through visual Studio code
How can I add

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio's Resources folder is available or you can use relative file location. If you type \img\image.png instead of C:\img\image.png. You can access the files in it from the file location of the Exe instead of the Absolute location.